# Navigating with react-navigation causes component to not show data, needs to rerender

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When I navigate with react-navigation, the screen that shows up (SearchPage - stateless functional component) has a `CategoriesMultiselect` (class component) which is missing the categories data (visually). The data definitely still exists, because When I scroll the page, the data shows up because it is rerendered.

How would I cause the `searchPage` to be rerendered when it is navigated to (or rerender the CategoriesMultiselect)?

code which navigates:

```
import FBLoginButton from './button/view'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Container, Text, Button } from 'native-base'
import VepoHeader from '../../formControls/header/view'
import { styles } from '../../style'

import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation'

class LoginView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.buttonPress = this.buttonPress.bind(this)
      }

      buttonPress() {
        console.log('called')
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Search')
      }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={{ backgroundColor: '#27a562' }}>
        <Container
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            height: '100%',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
          }}>
          <FBLoginButton />
          <Text style={{ color: '#FFF', 
          marginTop: 20,
          marginBottom: 20 }}>OR</Text>
          <Button
            block
            style={{
              ...styles.labelHeight,
              borderRadius: 4,
              borderWidth: 0.5,
              borderColor: '#FFF',
              width: 250,
              marginLeft: 'auto',
              marginRight: 'auto',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',

            }}
            onPress={this.buttonPress}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 13.5}}>Continue without Login</Text>
          </Button>
        </Container>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default withNavigation(LoginView)
```

I need to call forceupdate() on CategoriesMultiselect after navigating to the stateless functional searchPage component.

How do I do that?

Comment: but I can see you are using react-navigation not react-native-navigation(wix)

Comment: @Nima Yikes. Thank you for pointing that out. I've just edited it.